# how to use subtotal in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following data

```
 CODE  NAME   AMOUNT VAT  TOTALAMT FLAG
  10   test1   100    10    110     1
  08   test2    0     0      0      1
  05   test3   10     0      0      2
  03   test4    0     0      0      2
```

I want a query which give the following output.
(Subtotal according to FLAG)

```
 CODE  NAME   AMOUNT VAT  TOTALAMT FLAG
  10   test1   100    10    110      1
  08   test2    0     0      0       1
 NULL SUBTOTAL 100    10    110    NULL
  05   test3   10     0      0       2
  03   test4    0     0      0       2
 NULL SUBTOTAL  10    0     10     NULL
TOTAL          110    10    120    NULL
```

Comment: hint, GROUP BY with ROLLUP.

Comment: I don't understand how the grand total for `TOTALAMT` can be `120`, given that there is only a single value of `110` for the entire table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT Code,
         isNULL(NAME,'SUBTOTAL') AS NAME,
         SUM(Total) AS Total,
         SUM(Vat) AS Vat,
         SUM(TotalAmt) AS 
         TotalAmt,
         Flag 
   FROM TABLE GROUP BY ROLLUP(Flag,Code,Name);
```

Comment: This [won't give the desired result](http://rextester.com/YLV81923), and also the OP has no `Total` column.  You should test your code before you post.

Comment: My table  Name and columns is different :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CODE) AS CODE,
    NAME,
    MAX(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
    MAX(VAT) AS VAT,
    MAX(TOTALAMT) AS TOTALAMT,
    FLAG
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    FLAG, NAME
WITH ROLLUP;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
;with cte
as
(
 select
  CODE,
  NAME,
  AMOUNT,
  VAT,
  TOTALAMT,
  FLAG
  from t1

  union aLL

  select
  CODE=NULL,
  NAME='SUBTOTAL',
  AMOUNT = SUM(AMOUNT),
  VAT = SUM(VAT),
  TOTALAMT = SUM(TOTALAMT),
  FLAG
  from T1
  GROUP BY FLAG
)
SELECT
*
FROM CTE
ORDER BY FLAG,CODE DESC
```